# PayPal rest c#: how to Attach pdf file to invoice?

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox, attachment, paypal-rest-sdk

i want to attach a pdf file to a invoice i created with the paypal rest api but somehow the pdf just disappear while creating the invoice without throwing any exception.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"); //edited
var converted = uri.AbsoluteUri;

var invoice = new Invoice()
{
 ....
 attachments = new List<FileAttachment>()
 {
     new FileAttachment
     {
          name = "pdf.pdf",
          url = converted
     },
 }
}
```

I also tried to use a pdf file thats available online didnt work as well.
The invoice is created but without any attachments.

Without any errors from paypal response iam not able to figure out whats the issue.

Note: <s>I use the sandbox(maybe here is the problem?)</s>

The issue also appears in live version

Comment: Attachments is read only... I am trying to see how to add them as well. But for now, it won't take attachments from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the definition of Paypal's invoicing API [file attachment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/#definition-file_attachment),
the url must be in `Uri` format.

> url string
>
> The URL of the attached file, which can be downloaded.
>
> Format: uri.

Obviously a file located in your local drive won't suffice.

Comment: i just recognized that i didnt mention that i also tried an online pdf file (http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf)